# Basic Graph Theory on degree sequences.

Tags: graph-theory

Here is a tricky one.

In a graph with 8 vertices, seven have degrees 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7. Find the degree of $8^{th}$ vertex?

The question further asks about its chromatic number?

Comment: The first part, though seems easy, eludes me. Once it is done the rest easily follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, try to draw the graph. The vertex of degree $7$ must be connected by edges to each of the other vertices, and the vertex of degree $1$ must therefore be connected **only** to the vertex of degree $7$. Then pick a vertex to have degree $6$, and fill in its edges; there’s only one way to fill them in. At that point you should have identified the vertices of degrees $1,6$, and $7$, and you’ll have five vertices of degree $2$. Pick one of them to be the given vertex of degree $2$; you have four remaining vertices, currently of degree $2$, that are supposed to have degrees $3,4,5$, and ?. Connect two of them by an edge, and choose one of those to be the known vertex of degree $3$, leaving three vertices unassigned, two of degree $2$ and one of degree $3$. Now play with them.

Comment: Yup, it works. I was stuck trying to fix 7,1,2.. instead of 7,6,1,2,3.. Thanks.

Comment: @Uma: You’re welcome.